# Get input values from cloned Input in jquery

Tags: jquery, clone

I have a div containing four different input tags (input, select, file-input) and I am cloning the whole div along with the inputs. Now I am struggling to get entered values from cloned inputs. While cloning it clones the same id from the 1st. also i need to store those values in an object. Each time when I clone I need to get those cloned input values and store it new object.

Comment: Please make this question more clear by adding a working code snippet that shows how you clonned the node.

Comment: *While cloning it clones the same id* - there's your problem.  IDs must be unique.  Remove all IDs from the code that's going to be cloned (so it doesn't clone the IDs) and use classes and relative DOM navigation.  Can't provide any more specific details without code clone and "get entered values" code.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript do not allow duplicate id, you have to found an other way for diplicating your inputs.
If you check in your browser dev tool ( ctrl+shift+i) you will confirm the error.
In contrast, class can be duplicated. So if you decide to duplicate input with the same class, there's no problem and then you will identify those cloned input with their parent div